# Adding White Noise to a camera

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I need to do a grid shearch to caracherize the error of the camera I'm working with in gazebo.

For that I need to add white noise to the camera.

In the URDF I see that Gazebo already does that.

```
    <noise>
      <type>gaussian</type>
      <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.
           That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
           channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
      <mean>0.0</mean>
      <stddev>0.007</stddev>
    </noise>
```

Are there any instructions or something I can read to know more about how I should tune this 2 parameters? Any examples/tutorials here is Gazebo?

I hope Gazebo doesn't use just rand() function to generate this white noise. It doesn't right?

The ideia I have is to leave the mean at zero and just increase the stddev, but to what number?

Thx for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8874/adding-white-noise-to-a-camera/) by [Paulo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1111/paulo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm guessing trial and error will be your friend.
I'm currently using mean = 0.0 and stddev = 0.1

If you run the simulation and press 'ctrl' and 't' it brings up a Gazebo Topic Selector.

Accessing the 'gazebo.msgs.ImageStamped'  option lets you see the camera sensor image with noise.
you can adjust your stddev to suit.

hope this helps

tony

---

Originally posted by [tonylindsay](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1237/tonylindsay/) with karma: 16 on 2015-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0